# Jailbroken iPod touch stuck in boot

Tags: ipod-touch, jailbreak, ios, reboot

I jailbroke my iPod touch 4g running iOS 6.1 yesterday. I got SiriPort, but it kept crashing my iPod and booting into safe mode. I reinstalled it, and took it for a test run, and of course, it crashed. This time however, it did not boot to safe mode. I shut it down, and tried to turn it back on, however, it seems to be stuck in the reboot. I have tried to restore it with iTunes, but i get errors saying that it can't connect to the iPod. It also couldn't connect to it even before it was jailbroken. Please help, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Leave it for an hour or so. If it still isn't booting, you need to restore your iPod.
I would do this ASAP, because Apple is readying for the 6.1.1 release, which may block the current evasi0n exploit.

To force restore your iPod, enter DFU mode as shown below:

- Connect the device to your computer and launch iTunes
- Turn the device off (hold down the power button and home button at the top of the device)
- Hold down the sleep/power button and home button together for exactly 10 seconds, then release the power button
- Continue to hold down the Home button until a message appears in iTunes telling you an iPod in recover mode has been detected

After that, it should work in iTunes and you can restore.

Comment: How would I go about putting my device into DFU mode with a broken home button?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible. There is a method that allows you to enter DFU mode with redsn0w without the home button [here](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=23009), however that requires the device to appear in iTunes.